# add navigation to react native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I an trying my hands on react native apps.

I have created an app which as of now has a 3 screen.

Landing Screen, Home Screen & Settings Screen. What I want is that user lands on Landing Screen and there two tabs (Home & Settings) are displayed.

What I have achieved is that user lands on Home Screens and both tabs are displayed but I am unable to make Landing Screen as default page having tabs.

Sample application is available @ [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/@nikhilgupta/tab-navigation-1)

Any help will be appreciated.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // 1.0.0-beta.27

import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'; // 0.19.0

import "@expo/vector-icons"; // 6.3.1

class LandingScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
       title: "Landing Screen", 
       tabBarLabel: "Landing",
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="menu" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Landing!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
       title: "Home Screen", 
       tabBarLabel: "Home",
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
       title: "Settings Screen", 
       tabBarLabel: "Settings",
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="loyalty" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainTabNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { 
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Settings: { 
      screen: SettingsScreen,
    },
  },  
  {
    tabBarOptions: 
    {
      showIcon: true
    }
  }
);

const MainStackNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    Function: {
      screen: MainTabNav,
    },
    Landing: {
      screen: LandingScreen,
    },
  }
);

export default MainStackNav;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you this [medium article](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c) that explain how to setup a very common authentication flow for a react-native app.

It implements two different StackNavigator.
One for the guest, one when you're logged in.

Then you'll find a TabNavigator in which you can also nest others stacknavigator.

Comment: Hi Louis, I have gone through the article but it's not related to my question. I want my landing page to have tabs related to two diff screens. My current implementation already shows tabs but tab1 becomes landing page which I don't want.

Comment: What I have realized is that it's not possible to have tab navigation on screen/page that is not part of tab navigation. So the approach I choose is to have a button "Get Started" on the landing page that opens the Drawer consisting of Imp screens.